# Error con tildes y ñs al importar celdas desde excel - JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, utf-8

tengo un formulario con un jtable el cual carga un archivo de excel dentro de el, el problema es que no me carga las ñs o caracteres especiales
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me salen esos símbolos de pregunta.
este el el codigo del boton agregar

```
private void btn_importarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jtabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
            modelo.removeRow(i);
            i -= 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos Excel (*.xls)", "xls");
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("BUSCAR ARCHIVO");
    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        File f = new File(ruta);
        try {
            Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
            Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
            int row = s.getRows();
            int col = s.getColumns();
            String[] datos;
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                datos = new String[col];
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    Cell c = s.getCell(j, i);
                    datos[j] = c.getContents();
                    System.out.print(c.getContents());
                }
                System.out.println("");
                if (i == 0) {
                    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(datos);
                } else {
                    modelo.addRow(datos);
                }

            }
            jtabla.setModel(modelo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Ya estuve investigando sobre convertir a UTF-8 pero no se en que momento deberia hacerlo y como. intente convertir el archivo `FILE` o al momento del `getContents` pero no me da resultado ninguna forma.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: puedes hacer `String content = new String(c.getContents.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: Ya lo intente y no me funciona tampoco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la Solución

tuve que cambiar las librerías a usar, en la pregunta estuve usando la ***jxl*** pero después use **poi-3.7-20101029.jar**

este es el código

*Librerías*

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
```

*Boton*

```
DecimalFormat formatDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#");

private void btn_importarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jtabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
            modelo.removeRow(i);
            i -= 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos Excel (*.xls)", "xls");
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("BUSCAR ARCHIVO");
    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        File f = new File(ruta);

        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(ruta);
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            String[] datos;

            for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                int cols = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                datos = new String[cols];

                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    try {
                        datos[j] = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        datos[j] = formatDecimal.format(row.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(datos);
                } else {
                    modelo.addRow(datos);
                }
            }
            jtabla.setModel(modelo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("general " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

tuve que usar el decimalformat para los datos numéricos enteros porque me daba error